# How to round a decimal amount, in c sharp, to a nearest fractional value given by users?

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Requirement**

User has option to choose fractional value as a rule. For example 0.5, or 0.01, or 0.33, or 0.1.

Amount is for example 12.46 and rounding rule is 0.01.

I am not sure if i have explained it correctly.

Any answer is highly appreciated. Khankooouuu in advance.

Comment: Are you wanting to do this in c# or in sql-server?

Comment: If it's C#, then please remove the sql-server tag. It's misleading to people who save this tag as their favourite.

Comment: You need to clarify this question quite a bit. You do realize that 0.46 represents a fraction, correct? Are you saying it needs to round to the nearest half, tenth, third or 100th based on how something is configured?

Answer (score 5):

```
public class Test
{
    static double round(double what, double to)
    {
        return to * Math.Round(what/to);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(round(3.5, 1));
        Console.WriteLine(round(3.44, 1));
        Console.WriteLine(round(3.44, 0.1));
        Console.WriteLine(round(1.68, 0.33));
        Console.WriteLine(round(1.59, 0.33));
    }
}
```

outputs

> 4
>   3
>   3.4
>   1.65
>   1.65

Answer (score 0):

You can round a decimal by using the Decimal.Round() method with an overload of Decimal and an integer for how many decimal places.  See [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6be1edhb.aspx).

As for the part to see how many decimal places the user wants to use if they put in a decimal value, you can convert that to a string and count the characters after the decimal point:

```
decimal UserDecimal;
string UserString = UserDecimal.ToString();
int DecimalPlaces = UserString.SubString(UserString.IndexOf(".")).Length;
```

At the end of all that, DecimalPlaces will be the amount of decimal places the user has implicitly requested with their inputed decimal value.

This what you're looking for??

Comment: I don't think Decimal.Round() will work if he wants to round to the nearest multiple of 0.33 - so in this case, 12.46 would become 12.33